# Not able to start juggernaut server as a background processs/service

Tags: services, upstart, ruby

I am using ruby on rails application to implement chat. I am not able to setup juggernaut server in production mode.

I followed [this guide](http://www.denofubiquity.com/nosql/412/) to setup redis. and its working perfectly fine.

Then I followed [this for setting up juggernaut](https://gist.github.com/1055322). But when I am trying to start juggernaut its not working.

Here is the out for grep commands to check that redis is working but juggernaut is not.

[image]

When I am trying to stop/start redis server its gives me output ie:

```
 Starting/Stopping redis-server: redis-server.
```

But nothing when i m doing the same for juggernaut. Check screenshot.

[image]

Some other things to check what actually going on:

1. Executable file permissions to /etc/init.d/juggernaut file -- YES

   ```
       -rwxr-xr-x 1 fizzy fizzy 1310 Sep 19 11:06 juggernaut
   ```
2. PIDFILE=/var/run/juggernaut.pid' is defined. Does that exist? --- NO
3. In the 'start' part it runs 'chown juggernaut:juggernaut'. Does the user juggernaut exist and is it member of the group juggernaut?  -- YES/YES

   ```
     cat /etc/group
         redis:x:1002:
         juggernaut:x:113:

     groups juggernaut
         juggernaut : juggernaut
   ```
4. Running sudo juggernaut start the server, but i want to it to keep on running in background process/service.

[image]

I am stuck now. Can anybody help me.

**EDIT**

```
    fizzy@li136-198:~$ sudo ls -l /usr/bin/juggernaut 
              ls: cannot access /usr/bin/juggernaut: No such file or directory
     fizzy@li136-198:~$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/bin/juggernaut 
            lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 40 Sep 20 02:48 /usr/local/bin/juggernaut -> ../lib/node_modules/juggernaut/server.js
```

I tried changing

```
        DAEMON=/usr/bin/juggernaut
```

to

```
        DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/juggernaut
```

after that i tried restarting the juggernaut using

```
         sudo /etc/init.d/juggernaut start
```

Server started but not as background process/service.

**EDIT**

Running script in debuggin mode:

```
   + PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
   + DAEMON=/usr/bin/juggernaut
   + NAME=Juggernaut2
   + DESC=Juggernaut2
   + PIDFILE=/var/run/juggernaut.pid
   + test -x /usr/bin/juggernaut
   + exit 0
```

**EDIT**

```
    fizzy@li136-198:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/juggernaut start
    + PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
    + DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/juggernaut
    + NAME=Juggernaut2
    + DESC=Juggernaut2
    + PIDFILE=/var/run/juggernaut.pid
    + test -x /usr/local/bin/juggernaut
    + set -e
    + case "$1" in
    + echo -n 'Starting Juggernaut2: '
    Starting Juggernaut2: + touch /var/run/juggernaut.pid
    + chown juggernaut:juggernaut /var/run/juggernaut.pid
    + start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --umask 007 --pidfile /var/run/juggernaut.pid --chuid juggernaut:juggernaut --exec /usr/local/bin/juggernaut
    20 Sep 06:41:16 - Your node instance does not have root privileges. This means that the flash XML policy file will be served inline instead of on port 843. This will slow down initial connections slightly.
    20 Sep 06:41:16 - socket.io ready - accepting connections

    node.js:134
            throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
            ^
    Error: EADDRINUSE, Address already in use
        at Server._doListen (net.js:1106:5)
        at net.js:1077:14
        at Object.lookup (dns.js:153:45)
        at Server.listen (net.js:1071:20)
        at Object.listen (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/juggernaut/lib/juggernaut/server.js:51:21)
        at Object.listen (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/juggernaut/lib/juggernaut/index.js:9:10)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/juggernaut/server.js:21:12)
        at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
        at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
    + echo failed
    failed
    + exit 0
```

Here is the out for all the used ports

```
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdom:9312 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:mysql *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:6379                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:http-alt              *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:www                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:52433 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdo:53784 *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:smtp                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

Comment: Aside from anything else you certainly want the init.d file owned by `root:root`.

Comment: When you say "not as background" do you mean the init script didn't complete?

Comment: @poolie yaa.. I m sorry for using wrong terms...

Comment: **Let's continue this [in a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1388/discussion-between-poolie-and-mohit-jain)**

Answer (score 2):

What I would do to debug this sort of upstart problem is: edit `/etc/init.d/juggernaut` and change the shebang line at the top to add an `-x`, eg

```
#! /bin/bash -x
```

then try to start the service and you should see it print debug information, which hopefully will make it clear what's wrong.

**update:** the second last line

```
 + test -x /usr/bin/juggernaut
```

makes it pretty clear (to me :-) the init script is aborting because it thinks juggernaut is not installed.  You need to update that line to point to `/usr/local/bin/juggernaut`.

**update:** "address in use" means another process is listening on that socket, maybe another copy of juggernaut.  `netstat -tpl` will tell you.

Comment: Check my edit.. I think that make some sense..

Comment: Please actually run the command and add the output to your question.

Comment: check it now..I edit my question

Comment: yupp.. did that but now it saying some port is already in use.. :(

Comment: check my edit now..

Comment: cant we release a port. I tried restarting my server.. Still not working..

Comment: I guess you have some other service on the port that juggernaut wants to use. `netstat -tpl ` will tell you. You need to shut down one of them, or configure one to use a different port or ip address.

Comment: @pollie i have pasted the output in my question.. can u please help me..

Comment: Run with -p and it will show you which process is using the port.  I don't know which port juggernaut is trying to use.  http://juggernaut.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/juggernaut/README suggests you need configure it and suggests you use 5001.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1388/discussion-between-poolie-and-mohit-jain)